# Which NodeJs UI Framework is most suitable for EOSJS

Tags: development, javascript, eosjs

I'd like to know which Framework you should use in eosjs. I have little experience with JavaScript and so I don't know which Framework works best together with eosjs or does the framework even matter?

So far I read here in a question, one should use express, but then I read that express mainly is used for backend. I though if all I want is to let my user interact with my contract i would only need an UI with some buttons, input field an somehow sign transactions. I think my contract is the whole backend stuff, so currently i don't know which framework works best or will be the main framework to work with eosjs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very subjective thing. Personally I would recommend to learn **React  with Redux**.

Here is a little [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@nomanbinhussein/reactjs-todo-app-tutorial-with-redux-57ca14cae621)

The main advantage is that you can use [React](https://reactjs.org/) for the visual representation und decapsule it from the application logic which is build with [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Other stuff to look at would be
[Angular 4](https://angular.io/) (visual Framework)
[Vue](https://vuejs.org/) (visual Framework)
and maybe [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) if you want to write a Desktop application

Answer (score 5):

I heavily use eosjs with [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)+[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/), it is much more developer friendly and easier to learn than React when you want to scale. The first EOS browser extension, Scatter, also uses Vue for the frontend very effectively, so does [Bloks.io](http://bloks.io)(best EOS block explorer with wallet), [BetDice](https://betdice.one/?ref=ha4daojrgene)(biggest probably fair EOS gambling site) and many more.

Answer (score -2):

I use React. Similar code will run on iOS/Android (React Native), Xbox, Cross Platform OS' (with Electron.js)